# Extract template strings for i18n from Twig in Slim

Tags: internationalization, twig, translation, gettext, slim

I spend quite some time trying to figure out how to "compile" all my Twig templates in a Slim based application, to make sure all strings were ready to be picked up by `xgettext` for further processing and translation.

It turned out to be quite easy as soon as I had the right pieces of information put together, but I couldn't find any place on the internet telling me how to do exactly this with Twig in a Slim application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twig documentation has a fine example of [how to extract template strings](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html#extracting-template-strings). However, before you're able to do that, you need to pull the Twig environment out of your Slim application, [as described in the Slim Knowledge Base](http://help.slimframework.com/kb/views/using-twig-functions-inside-of-slim).

So, here's a modified version of the example from Twig documentation:

```
// Specify where your templates are located.
$tplDir = '/path/to/your/templates';

// Get the Twig environment from your Slim app, $app.
$twig = $app->view()->getEnvironment();

// Iterate over all your templates.
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($tplDir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY) as $file)
{
    // Force compilation.
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        $twig->loadTemplate(str_replace($tplDir.'/', '', $file));
    }
}
```